# image rectification using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tried to write a code with openCV, based on the algorithm that is mentioned in Trucco & Verri book pp. 159., in order to rectify stereo-images. The purpose of the rectification is to use them in producing DSM, although the code works properly but the results are wrong.

Can any one in the group can help me to fix the problem.

The input is as follows:

[image: the input image]

The current result is:

[image: the result is as below]

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat input, output;

    input = imread("E:\\Gray_Image.bmp", 1);

    double alpha = -0.0426, beta = -0.1871, gamma = -179.8781,
         dx =1, dy = 1, dz = 16750., f = 16750.;
    double w = (double)input.cols;

    double h = (double)input.rows;
    //the cmera intresic file is 

    Mat CAM = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
            f, 0, w / 2, 
            0, f, h / 2 - 20, 
            0, 0, 1 );

    // Rotation matrices around the X, Y, and Z axis
    Mat RX = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
            1, 0, 0, 
            0, cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 
            0, -sin(alpha), cos(alpha));

    Mat RY = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
            cos(beta), 0, -sin(beta), 
            0, 1, 0, 
            sin(beta), 0, cos(beta));

    Mat RZ = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
            cos(gamma), sin(gamma), 0, 
            -sin(gamma), cos(gamma), 0, 
            0, 0, 1);

    // Composed rotation matrix with (RX, RY, RZ)
    Mat R = RX * RY * RZ;
    //  cout << R << endl;

    Mat Te1 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) <<
                    dx,
                    dy,
                    dz);

    Mat Te2 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) <<
                    -dy,
                    dx,
                    0);

    Mat Te3 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) <<
                -(dx * dz),
                -(dy * dz),
                -(dx*dx + dy*dy));

    Mat e1 =  Te1 * (1.0 / (sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)));// * T;
    transpose(e1, Te1);

    Mat e2 = Te2 * (1.0 / (sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)));// * T;
    transpose(e2, Te2);
    Mat e3 = Te3 * (1.0 / (sqrt((dx*dx + dy*dy)*(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz))));// * T;                                   
    transpose(e3, Te3);

    Mat Re(3, 3, CV_32F); // 
    // add the above row matrix into one
    Te1.copyTo(Re.row(0));
    Te2.copyTo(Re.row(1));
    Te3.copyTo(Re.row(2));

    cout << CAM << endl;
    cout << Re << endl;
    warpPerspective(input, output, Re, input.size(), INTER_LANCZOS4);
    imshow("Input", input);
    imshow("Output", output);

    ////////////////////////////
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to ask a question. Furthermore, if you expect others to read your code, please take the time to format it legibly.

Comment: Hello Dan,is it better now? Can you give me some help.

Comment: Somewhat better :) Also, please attach a sample input image, your current output image, and if necessary describe how the result differs from your expectation.

Comment: A link to the mentioned algorithm would be of help

Comment: Dear Jeru, thanks for your reply, but  I think you have forgotten to add the link.

Comment: Gamma looks more like degrees than radians?